Implication of Neumann boundary condition for heat equations
I am reading C.Simpson's paper titled "Constructing variation of Hodge strucutre using Yang-Mills theory and applications to uniformization". There he gets a smooth positive function $u$ satisfies
$$u_{t}-\Delta u\leq C_{1}u+C_{2}$$ on $\Omega\times(0,T]$, where $\Omega$ is a domain with compact smooth boundary. In addition, $\partial_{\nu}u_{|\partial\Omega}=0$ and $u_{0}=u(x,0)$ is a positive constant.
Then he concluded that $u$ is bounded on the finite interval $[0,T]$ due to the maximum principle. I am confused that $u$ is bounded by what? I guess it is by the intial value $u_{0}$ and the two constant $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$.
My idea is to construct a solution $f$ to the equation $u_{t}-\Delta u= C_{1}u+C_{2}$ with the initial and boundary values set as those of $u$. And use comparison principle to show that $u\leq f$. Then by maximum principle we know that $f$ is bounded by the boundary and initial value of $u$. The problem is we still don't get the boundary value of $u$ controlled. So my question is how does the Neumann boundary condition influence the boundary value of $u$?
Or is there another way around?

If $f$ is initially independent of $x$, and satisfies Neumann boundary conditions, doesn't it remain independent of $x$ over time?
